# Should I store data on my computer

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud-storage

Over the few months I have used two piece of software on my computer

1. Microsoft Office
2. Google Chrome

I can access all my files on OneDrive through Microsoft office without having to save anything on my desktop.

My question is, from a security perspective, is it better to solely rely on cloud storage of my data, or is it better to have a copy on my hard-drive too, even if there is no practical benefit in my day-to-day life

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you don't even need a hard drive.  Just live-boot from a Ubuntu ISO USB (which has Libre Office and Firefox), and start working.

Comment: "Better" against what threat? Or, in other words, "secure from *what*?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend putting the data on both.

If you're worried about data theft, you're probably just as likely to have malware steal your files as you are to have malware steal your Microsoft account password (or have someone find your password in a leak somewhere because you reused it) and take your files from OneDrive.

The main reason to store it on both is for backups. If you get ransomware, or just a hardware failure, you've got a copy on OneDrive as a backup. I can tell you from experience that you're much more likely to lose your data to a disk failure than you are from malware. Backups are *extremely*  important.

My recommendation would be to enable two-factor authentication (2FA) on your Microsoft account, in order to help protect it, and use a password manager such as KeePass so that you can have random passwords everywhere instead of re-using the same password in a bunch of places, which is a major risk.